# Error CS0246 when I want to publish the current project

Tags: acumatica

I get error "CS0246" When I want to publish my current project

[image]

Aplicacion DAC:

[image]

InventoryItemAplication DAC:

[image]

InventoryItemMaint Graph:

[image]

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `using` directive in the graph to reference the DAC namespace.
[image]

Comment: Hi Hugues, I forgot to mention that I tried to do that, when I add "using SalesDemoDashboards2019R2;" in InventoryItemMaint graph nothing happens

Comment: Nothing happened is really not telling much here, did you save the file? Did the icon turned from enabled to disabled after saving? Did you re-publish the customization?

Comment: If you're looking at runtime code in visual studio and expecting something to happen after adding the using directive, it's not gonna happen. You need to save/update and publish runtime code.

Comment: I agree with you, I have to do all that, but when I add "using SalesDemoDashboards2019R2" in the graph I get the next message: "The type or namespace SalesDemoDashboards2019R2 could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)", that's what I meant when I said nothing happens

Comment: It already works, Huges, visual studio doesn't recognize the code but from the code editor it does, thanks so much!

Comment: Alright, this was my suspicion. This behavior is normal because it is runtime code.

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting your InventoryItemMaint_Extension class in the SalesDemoDashboards2019R2 namespace instead of PX.Objects.IN

Comment: Hi Patrick, InventoryItemMaint_Extension class is the graph that uses Stock Items screen, Aplicacion and InventoryItemAplication DAC are new classes. So, I need to integrate the new DACs in PX.Objects.IN namespace, isn't it?

Comment: Technically, you can do it one way or another both will work but you need it to get it right.