# Auto Generated File in temp directory causing errors while Publishing

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to publish my code but every time this error comes up. couldn't figure out the problem causing this . I am using vs2019.

**C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3ae3db50\386f86a2\App_Web_ysujl3yj.1.cs(34,0): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MediaTypeHeaderValue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Am I missing any package or reference ?
Has anyone encountered this error before? Is it related to IIS?
P.S: While debugging it runs smoothly and not showed any error or exception.

Updated:
[Error List Shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvUsa.png)

but Unbale to find this file in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

- Clean solution then rebuild it.
- Go to  **Solution Explorer**. Right click on Solution. Go to  **Properties**. Go to  **Configuration Manager**. Check if the checkboxes under  **Build**  are checked or not. If any or all of them are unchecked, then check them and try build the solution again.
- Remove the project reference and then adding it back in again, and check if all those missing dll file exists in the bin folder.
- Delete bin/obj folder, build again and try to restart Visual Studio.

Some times we might miss **using ** keyword.

For  further details refer [SO-Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940169/error-cs0246-when-i-want-to-publish-the-current-project), [SO-Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590993/net-core-publish-compilation-errors).

Comment: @Axxiiim , If answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as an answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: How to get to know that I am missing 'Using' keyword in any file. because when I try to Clean and Rebuild the solution it works perfectly fine but when ever I try to Publish the code I am getting this error.

Comment: Have you checked references ?

Comment: Yes I did but there is no progress

Comment: can you please check the updated question once ?

Comment: what is the namespace where mediatypeheadervalue is present? [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue?view=net-6.0),[Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721351/the-type-or-namespace-cannot-be-found-are-you-missing-a-using-directive-or-an-a)